# How to change postition of a dynamicaly created text box?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

Stack overflow! I've been here multiple times and I've always managed to find an answer to my questions! But now I come forward with a problem that I can't find the solution for, Heres a bit of c# that generates a new TextBox when you press a button, How do I move the text box after its creation?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int cLeft = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewTextBox();
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
            txt.Left = 100;
            txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
            cLeft = cLeft + 1;
            return txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var createdTextBox = AddNewTextBox(); createdTextBox.Location = new Point(x, y);`.

Comment: That only works for one instance of the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the dynamic controls on a form, use the controls collection. For this example I added a new button on the form which moves all the text boxes on the form.

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)  // all controls on form
    {
        if (c is Button) continue;   // don't move buttons
        if (c is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)  // move textboxes
            c.Top += 1;  // move down 1 pixel
            c.Left += 1;  // move right 1 pixel
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you also be able to provide an example of input? Eg if it buttons instead of text boxes, how would each button be differentiated?

Comment: All controls have a tag property. You can set this to a string or linked object. Then in code you  can check `if (myctrl.tag == '5') ....`. You can also link another control: `mybutton.tag = mytextbox`